# How to construct an array of pointer to structure and assign the value to the created structure

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create an array of pointer with this structure:

```
struct No {
    int decimal;
    char *binary;
    char *octal;
    char *hexadecimal;
};
```

and I have two functions to construct the array and print out the array:

```
void constructArray (No *Number, int size) {
    No **temp = new No *[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp[i]->decimal = rand() % 1000;
        temp[i]->binary = "0";
        temp[i]->octal = "0";
        temp[i]->hexadecimal = "0";
    }
}

void printArray (No *Number, int size) {
    cout << "Decimal\t" << "Binary\t\t\t" << "Octal\t\t" << "Hexadecimal" << endl;
    No **temp = new No *[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << temp[i]->decimal << "\t"
            << temp[i]->binary << "\t\t\t"
            << temp[i]->octal << "\t\t"
            << temp[i]->hexadecimal << endl;
    }
}
```

then I call them inside the main function:

```
int main() {
    No *number;
    int size = (rand() % 9) + 1;
    constructArray(number,size);

    printArray(number,size);
}
```

The program was successfully compiled and run but nothing is output. What's the problem with my code? Is there something wrong with the way I initialize the array here? How can I overcome this problem? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: In `constructArray`, where dod you update the `number`? You are leaking a lot of memory, are you from Java background by any chance?

Comment: Why did you use C tag?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I saw your comments, that's why clarifying :)

Comment: No output?? Or seg fault?  You have a pretty obvious bug in `constructArray` that should seg fault.  You allocate an array of pointers but don't allocate structures for them to point to nor otherwise initialize those pointers.  You then store data into wherever those uninitialized pointers point.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the application? Debuggers allow you to single step through your code and then you will be able to see what is going wrong. Google 'debugging'

Comment: Good call JSF. That will do it.

Comment: @JSF: Segmentation faults are just one of near-infinite potential symptoms of that bug. Never _expect_ a segfault or say that you "should" get one.

Comment: Try it a few times.  A seg fault is not certain.  But it is so likely, that I am correct to expect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your intent requires adding a line where you have

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    temp[i]->decimal = rand() % 1000;
```

You should have

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    temp[i] = new No;
    temp[i]->decimal = rand() % 1000;
```

Comment: int main() {
    No *number;
    int size = (rand() % 9) + 1;
    constructArray(number,size);

you need to set Number to something. like Number = New no;

Comment: Your "No" class will need a constructor to init all the member data in it.